# angular 2 referencing external js file in index.html

Tags: angular

I am making a simple angular 2 application using angular cli tool. In my code I have to include jquery.js file in my index.html. jquery.js is under node_modules directory but the statement

`<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>`

in the index.html seems to be not working:

Failed to load resource: http://localhost:4200/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js
the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

How can I make sure that the jquery.js is included in index.html? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi.. are you using webpack also? ..and typescript?

Comment: @fscamuzzi81 Yes I am using typescript and webpack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to include a global library, you have to add the jquery.js file in the `scripts` array from angular-cli.json:

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
]
```

After this, restart `ng serve` if it is already started.

Comment: Thank you very much Tudor. Short, simple and to the point answer!

Answer (score 4):

There is a new way to deal with *external libraries* using **@types**

In order to install/use **jquery**, you just need to install it in your project using

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

and then in **tsconfig.json**,under **types**, add its reference accordingly as shown,

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,

    "types": [
      "jquery",    //<<<<-----add here
      "hammerjs",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the benefit by using this way ? i mean by using `@types`

Comment: earlier there was no mechanism to manage external libraries but now    using types only in one file you can manage your external libraries...

Comment: which one file ? is there any link related to that mechanism would be more helpful if you provide , btw thanks :)

Comment: unfortunately I don't think any official doc is available for the same but take a look here- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/typescript-configuration.html and google it for me. I will get the things easily.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution micronyks. I did not try it right now but I will look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you don't need to put it in index.html instead put this entry in `angular-cli.json` file

Like this:

```
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/wow.js/dist/wow.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "....Other Libs..."
      ]
```

Then make sure you have installed jQuery properly before use

Also check the root path while giving relative path in the angular-cli.json file

Answer (score 1):

If you use webPack and Typescript you can do something like this:

in your vendor.ts file import jquery:

```
/ RxJS.
import "rxjs";

// Angular 2.
import "@angular/common";
import "@angular/compiler";
import "@angular/core";
import "@angular/http";
import "@angular/platform-browser";
import "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import "@angular/router";

// Reflect Metadata.
import "reflect-metadata";

// Other vendors for example jQuery, Lodash or Bootstrap
// You can import js, ts, css, sass, ...

import "jquery"; //<-- HERE IS JQUERY
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "angular2-toaster/lib/toaster.css";
import "angular2-toaster/angular2-toaster";

import "ng2-slim-loading-bar";
import "ng2-slim-loading-bar/style.css";
import "ng2-modal";
import "ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal";
```

then in your webpack.dev.js use plug in to import it in every component without need to import it manually:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "polyfills": "./polyfills.ts",
        "vendor": "./vendor.ts",
        "app": "./app/main.ts",

    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html']
    },
    output: {
        path: "./app_build",
        filename: "js/[name]-[hash:8].bundle.js"
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: "babel-loader",

                // Skip any files outside of your project's `src` directory
                //include: [
                //  "app_build",
                //],
                exclude: [
                  path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")
                ],
                // Only run `.js` and `.jsx` files through Babel
                test: /\.js/,

                // Options to configure babel with
                query: {
                    plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator'],
                    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0'],
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: "ts"
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: "html"
            },
            //{
            //    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|ico|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)$/,
            //    loader: "file?name=assets/[name]-[hash:6].[ext]",
            //},
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|ico)$/,
                //include:  path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/img"),
                loader: 'file?name=/assets/img/[name]-[hash:6].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
              //  exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'file?name=/assets/fonts/[name].[ext]'
            },
            // Load css files which are required in vendor.ts
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("css/[name]-[hash:8].bundle.css", { allChunks: true }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ["app", "vendor", "polyfills"]
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(
            [
                "./app_build/js/",
                "./app_build/css/",
                "./app_build/assets/",
                "./app_build/index.html"
            ]
        ),
        // inject in index.html
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./index.html",
            inject: "body"
        }),
        // JQUERY PLUGIN HERE <-- !!! HERE IS PLUG IN
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery'
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        //contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "app_build/"),
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: "minimal"
    }
};
```

Now everywhere in your code .ts you can use jquery like this:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';





@Component({
    selector: 'about',
    template: require('./about.component.html'),
    styles: [String(require('./about.component.scss'))]
})

export default class AboutComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    calendarElement: any;


    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.calendarElement = jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to follow [Nikhil Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41376442/1986423) suggestion in case of existing @type (like the case of jQuery)

However if you have library that export global variable (like jQuery) but does not have known @type file you can take a look at [my following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42531719/1986423)

Answer (score 0):

If @tudorciotlos answer does not work for you (like in my case) try this extended way:

```
  "scripts": [
    { "input": "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js", "bundleName": "renamed-script.js" }
  ]
```

```html
     <script src="renamed-script.js"></script>
```

[Source here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts)